# AngularJS - Change the scope of a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to set up an Angular Directive so that I can re-use a piece of HTML. I have managed to achieve this, but the problem I am facing is when I want to pass some value into that templated HTML, from the containing HTML.

For simplicity's sake, I will use an example of a customer that has multiple addresses (in this context, the customer is an object and each address instance is another object attached to the customer).

Example of the data:

```
var customer = {
    forename: "John",
    surname: "Smith",
    address1: {
        street: "123 Street",
        town: "Georgeville",
    },
    address2: {
        street: "67 Maple Grove",
        town: "SomeTown"
    }
};
```

Here is an example of my directive setup:

```
var module = angular.module(...);
module.directive("address", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: '/AddressView.html'
    };
});
```

And my attempted usage:

```
<div ng-model="customer">
    <div address></div>
    <div address></div>
</div>
```

And this is what I would like to do to be able to pass the customer's addresses across to the templated HTML:

```
<div ng-model="customer">
    <div address ng-model="customer.address1"></div>
    <div address ng-model="customer.address2"></div>
</div>
```

I may have misunderstood the purpose of directives, or this may not be possible, but if anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

Let me know if you need me to add any further information.

**Edit**

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N8COWt?p=preview) that I have set up to try to illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to isolate the scope for your directive so that things don't get confused for angular.
And your object is better structure this way:

```
var customer = {
    forename: "John",
    surname: "Smith",
    addresses: [
        address1: {
            street: "123 Street",
            town: "Georgeville",
        },
        address2: {
            street: "67 Maple Grove",
            town: "SomeTown"
        }
    ]
};
```

this way you can do this:

```
<div class="customer">
    <div address ng-repeat="address in customer.addresses">
        {{address.town}} {{address.street}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know why you'r using ng-model here?!
This is an example, but if you provide a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3510140) with an example code helping you will be easier.

## Update:

- First your ng-controller was in the wrong place you need to move it up so the address directive could be in the scope of the controller so it could access the address object.
- Second you have 2 undefined variables: street and town.
- And you need to isolate the scope so each directive don't mess with the variables of the other one.

Here's a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nsP8pW?p=preview).
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to work out how I could use that `address` HTML in multiple places (not necessarily within a collection of objects - I might have singular objects that I wish to pass into it). I will look into setting up a Plunker example.

Comment: Brilliant! It was the isolation I was missing and the passing of the object through the directive attribute. Time to read up on scope isolation. Cheers!

Comment: Check this website [egghead](http://www.egghead.io/), it has a great videos on AngularJS and isolate scope from video 16 through 20 and other interesting stuff.